# How to get comments from single post in template?

Tags: django

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    ...
```

views

```
def single_post(request,slug):
    p = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    cat = Category.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('single_post.html',{'p':p,'cat':cat},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How to get comments from single post in template?

Answer (score 1):

In the views:

```
def single_post(request,slug):
    p = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    cat = Category.objects.all()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    return render_to_response('single_post.html',{'p':p,'cat':cat, 'comments':comments},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the template, something like:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.body}}
{% endfor %}
```